# Why does this example for Array.prototype.fill() throw a TypeError?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I was reading through and familiarising myself with some ES-6 features when I came across this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill

If you look under **Examples**, the very first one shows:

```
[1, 2, 3].fill(4); // [4, 4, 4] semicolon expected or 'TypeError: [4, 4, 4].fill(...)[3] is undefined' prompt
```

From the syntax and description of the parameters, `[1, 2, 3].fill(4)` looks like a perfectly valid call that will default parameters `start` to 0 and `end` to 3. In my mind, the statement should execute perfectly without errors, like the rest of the examples. I tried it in the console, and Firefox didn't complain.

Can anyone explain why this example (potentially) raise a TypeError, or even complain about semicolon? And why does the error not happen in a simple console test?

At first I thought it must be a typographical error, but I'm beginning to think not. This is the ONLY example that supposedly raises errors, and the error message is pretty specific to this line.

Comment: I'm guessing this is generated documentation and there's just a bug in it.

Comment: I removed the comment. I think it's more confusing than helping. Someone added the comment because the example didn't have semicolons before: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill$compare?locale=en-US&to=822265&from=721433

Comment: Seems to work fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/f62kaso2/ when run in Firefox.

Comment: To be clear: Someone fixed the examples and added this additional comment. There is no need for the comment though. This should have been part of the edit reason, not the documentation.

Comment: The question is obsolete now :D

Comment: I guess it's really a documentation error, then. I'm glad StackOverflow is now the new bug-reporting center :D

Answer (score 2):

Everybody can edit the pages on MDN. [Someone fixed an issue with the examples and added that comment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill$compare?locale=en-US&to=822265&from=721433):

---

[image]

---

The examples before didn't have semicolons at the end:

```
[1, 2, 3].fill(4)               // [4, 4, 4]
[1, 2, 3].fill(4, 1)            // [1, 4, 4]
```

which lead to an error if you just copied and pasted them.

However, I think the comment is more confusing than helpful [so I removed it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill$compare?locale=en-US&to=825163&from=822265).